# jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css Problem

Tags: jquery-ui

I have Jquery-UI on my localhost site,everything was fine 3 or 4 days but today this error is appearing: syntax error
css/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css
Line 13 . This is where firebug says is the error: `.ui-helper-hidden{ display: none; }`

Comment: Mark as answer if it's the answer.

Answer (score 14):

You probably have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css"/>
```

Comment: GREAT! that was my problem. how did you get that?